# Is there a way to show hover over /tool tip information when i mouse over on spotfire Visualization title?

Tags: javascript, spotfire

I am looking to have a functionality like when user mouse over on a vis title it needs to show some additional information.

Please help me out .

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a js tooltip for this portion, but you can add additional information in the visualization description. Also, you can make this fin a different font, smaller, bold, etc so that it doesn't conflict with your title and everything else on your visualization.